# Do I need to backup my 12.04 system to upgrade to 12.04.1?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I want to upgrade to the new version of Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS, and i need to know if a backup of my system is needed.

My system:

- Ubuntu: 12.04 (precise) 32-bit
- GNOME: 3.4.2
- Kernel Linux: 3.5.2-030502-generic
- Processor: Intel® Pentium(R) Dual CPU E2220 @ 2.40GHz × 2

Comment: Can you post this in English please? If I understand correctly you want to backup your Ubuntu system and upgrade to 12.04.1? But you just have to apply updates as usual to your 12.04 system to get it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to backup or specially "upgrade" to 12.04.1 **if you are already on 12.04**.

Simply update as normal, or open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

---

Não há necessidade de fazer backup por causa do upgrade para a versão 12.04.1.

> Basta atualizar o sistema normalmente, abrir um terminal e executar o comando `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: Sempre é bom preveni do que remediar.

Comment: @BRvitorio Sim, se divertir com 12.04.1;) e aceitar essa resposta, por favor, se possível ... (marca de verificação à esquerda)